# How would I generate a donut chart of college program percentages out of 100 using Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, api, dictionary, charts

I'm trying to figure out how to use the [college scorecard API](https://github.com/RTICWDT/open-data-maker/blob/master/API.md) in Python 2.7 to create a donut chart consisting of percentage of degrees awarded in various studies such as Education, Biological Science, etc.

I'm debating on using the plotly pie chart to insert data, but I'm unsure how to implement JSON data from the college scorecard API which has 37 values (i.e. `academics.program_percentage.agriculture` + 36 more) related to different academia fields.

If it helps, this question is tied to a project I've been working which displays the most recent school year data on a modern looking page. The scary part is it's due Thursday.

This is what I've written thus far after *alot* of trial and error:

```
import requests
import json

def main():
    url = 'https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools.json'
    payload = {
        'api_key': "api_key_here",
        '_fields': ','.join([
            'school.name',
            'school.school_url',
            'school.city',
            'school.state',
            'school.zip',
            '2015.student.size',
        ]),
        'school.operating': '1',
        '2015.academics.program_available.assoc_or_bachelors': 'true',
        '2015.student.size__range': '1..',
        'school.degrees_awarded.predominant__range': '1..3',
        'school.degrees_awarded.highest__range': '2..4',
        'id': '240444',
    }
    data = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()
    for result in data['results']:
        print result

main()
```

Comment: It's hard to help you without an api key. Can you provide the data you get? Or what exactly is your problem? Are there any error messages? Is there a documentation to the college scorecard API?

Comment: So everything on the program works correctly, I'm more interested in figuring out how to connect all program percentages from the college scorecard API to a pie chart. Also, there is documentation. Here's the [URL](https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/data/documentation/)

Comment: There are tons of libraries and tools out there, e.g. https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887193 from [d3js homepage](https://d3js.org/), or https://python-graph-gallery.com/donut-plot/ etc.